# Performing queries on based on the output of a subquery

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to perform a query based on the output of a sub-query. I would join the tables and perform one big query but that forces the query to search the entire table of one of the tables. The goal is to have the who (from table1), the what (from table2) and the when (from table3).

Here's what I have,

```
SELECT 
DB1.TB1.`Date`, 
DB1.TB1.`Sequence`, 
DB1.TB1.`InstanceId` 
FROM
  (
  SELECT 
  DB1.TB2.`UserName` AS USER, 
  DB1.TB2.`FirstName`, 
  DB1.TB2.`LastName`, 
  DB1.TB3.`ObjectName` AS OBJECT,
  DB1.TB3.`ObjectType`
  FROM 
  DB1.TB2 
  INNER JOIN  DB1.TB3 ON  DB1.TB2.`UserName` = DB1.TB3.`UserName`
  INNER JOIN  DB1.TB4 ON  DB1.TB3.`ObjectName` = DB1.TB4.`ObjectName`
  WHERE 
  DB1.TB4.`ADD` = 'Y'   AND 
  DB1.TB2.`ADUC` NOT LIKE 'ServiceAccount' AND 
  DB1.TB3.`ObjectName` NOT IN ('ThisAdmin','ThatAdmin')
  ) AS MySubQuery
WHERE 
DB1.TB1.`UserName` LIKE 'USER' AND 
DB1.TB1.`ActionDetail` LIKE '%OBJECT%' 
ORDER BY 
DB1.TB1.`Date` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You are creating a temp table using a subquery and seems you want name this table MySubQuery but  ... you don'use these table name  in tye next where  condition .. and you are using the select from this temp table for join with value form the same table  ... seems no sense ..

Comment: At the beginning is better show  the (minimal)  data stucture ,, a proper sample od data and the result expected .. ..

Comment: Your query have tb4 but not mentioned in the description and you used DB1.TB1.`Date` but you did not select from tb1.

Comment: If you have performance issue you can put the where clause in the sub-query not out side of it.